# "File Open" dialog is missing sidebar items

Tags: finder, macos, sidebar

I'm having the strangest issue since updating to OS X El Capitan. My "Open File" dialogs show the sidebar but all my main (and useful) locations are missing. Take a look at this screenshot. This screenshot shows Keychain Access but this happens in Safari when I'm trying to attach a file to Gmail for example, or uploading an image to Facebook.

What I would like is for the sidebar to show my home directories, such as Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc.

Help?

[image]

Comment: Only in file-picker dialogs, or in Finder windows too?

Comment: Only in the file-picker dialogs @Tetsujin, Finder itself shows the sidebar content as it should.

Comment: I have this too - and it also does it in Chrome. Reboot temporarily fixes it. Seems like an El Cap bug.

Comment: Same problem, you can go to Finder>Preferences>Sidebar and check them all, they will remain there in Finder... but NOT in any programs. For example, I open Photoshop CC 2015 and if you drag the folders you want into the Favorites area, they will NOT be there when you reopen the program. Same for ALL programs across the board. This is very frustrating.

Comment: This sucks.. same problem.  Still here in 10.11.3.

Comment: There's a bigger problem somewhere.  My sidebar is missing all drives, volumes, and the computer itself.  All but the computer are selected for display in Finder preferences (and originally the computer was too).  If I reactivate the computer's visibility using the checkbox, the setting is ignored and the checkbox clears itself.  Sometimes it'll clear itself while the prefs dialog is still open.  Finder = wholly defective

Comment: problem still here in 10.11.5 for me...

Comment: problem still exists for me 10.11.6.  reboot fixes it for a week or two

Comment: Same here, happens from time to time and a reboot is the fix.

Comment: Seeing the same issue on Sierra 10.12.6 after getting a new Mac and restoring it from a TimeMachine backup.

Comment: 10.11.6. The one-liner removed all my bookmarks in Finder, did nothing for "file open" dialogs. Be careful.

Comment: I added a working, simple solution at the bottom of this thread. Have a look at that. Unfortunately, due to the rank-based-on-votes system I guess many people won't see it until it gets more votes and "floats up".

Comment: A simple restart worked for me

Answer (score 157, accepted):

1. Go to your user library in Finder. Hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd> while opening the **Go** menu and click **Library**.
2. Navigate to the **Preferences** folder.
3. Remove any files that are or contain `com.apple.finder.plist`. (The removal of those files will very likely reset your **Favourites** list in Finder.)
4. Restart or log out and log back in again then empty the trash and try again.

   Restarting might not be necessary. As [madpoet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/159998/madpoet) says:

   > You can also *relaunch* Finder if you don't want to reboot or log out. Right click on Finder icon while you're pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd> and you'll see the **Relaunch** option there.
   >
   > [image: Relaunch Finder.]

---

Alternatively, you can use this Bash oneliner by [Christophe Marois](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/111093/christophe-marois):

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences && sudo find com.apple.finder.plist* -exec rm {} \; && killall Finder
```

Comment: This finally did it!  I had to remake my favorites though,

Comment: That is pretty hardcore... lol. I clearly see why you're at 11.7k rep ;)

Comment: You can also "relaunch" finder if you don't want to reboot or log out. Right click on finder icon while you're pressing "alt" key and you'll see the "Relaunch" there

Comment: That did it. Bash one-liner: `cd ~/Library/Preferences && sudo find com.apple.finder.plist* -exec rm {} \; && killall Finder`

Comment: @ChristopheMarois That managed to just remove Favourites completely from Finder with no fix for the file open/save dialog.

Comment: @ConstantMeiring sorry about that, it did fix it for me

Comment: Works for me. I had to restart, relaunch finder was not enough.

Comment: Yay! This worked. It brought back all my previous favorites. I also had to restart.

Comment: Worked for me as well (used the bash one-liner); also restored shortcuts to recent projects in Xcode.

Comment: Fixed for me but needed to log out and not just kill Finder! @ConstantMeiring the favourites disappered befor the logout, but then they came back as they were before!

Comment: Keep your old `com.apple.finder.plist` around safe somewhere just in case this wipes out something you care about (e.g., all your Desktop settings). After doing this, you can restore the old `plist` and the fix seems to stick.

Comment: The Open/Save dialogs are not a Finder function, so restarting Finder alone may not be adequate.  The Items are set via Finder though, so I suppose it makes sense that they're stored in Finder's prefs.

Comment: the bash one liner doesn't work for me

Comment: I usually solve the problem restarting osx, without removing anything. I was looking for something that doesn't require this restart.

Comment: Used one liner from @ChristopheMarois - needed a full restart. (Not rebooted for ~2 months so was probably due ;))

Comment: You don't need to do any of this. All you need to do is relaunch the Finder. Hit Cmd-Option-Esc, select "Finder", hit "Relaunch". That's it.

Comment: One liner just removed everything, didn't solve anything, had to use answer below by going to preferences.

Comment: This worked for me without rebooting. I did have to restart Finder.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel Log out and in also worked for me (while relaunch didn't).

Comment: I have the same issue on Sierra 10.12.6 after getting a new Mac and restoring it from a TimeMachine backup, and this solution unfortunately does _not_ help. After the Finder restart I get weird behavior, dragging stuff into the favorites gives the wrong icons, it doesn't show up in open file dialogs, the finder settings > sidebar > favorite checkboxes can't be disabled, and after another Finder restart all favorites are gone again. Maybe a new bug in 10.12.6 or deleting that plist file is not enough anymore.

Comment: Only works for me temporarily. Eventually it reoccurs. FYI, there's also a tread I started re this issue on Apple forums... https://discussions.apple.com/message/32284043 -- none of us there found a permanent solution.

Comment: This is a known bug and should be solved in _High Sierra_, according to [@jamarjus answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299902/193779).

Comment: There's a better solution below that worked for me. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305406/6378

Comment: For those who don't know what <kbd>⌥</kbd> is, it's the Option/Alt key on Mac keyboards.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue and fixed it in the following way:

1. While in a "Open File" or "Save As" dialog box (that doesn't show Favorites), drag any folder to the sidebar. This will create a "Favorites" category in the sidebar that only shows that folder.
2. Reboot.

After rebooting, all of the dialog box sidebars should show Favorites as it appears in Finder, synchronized.

Comment: This isn't a fix - it's a temporary workaround - it goes away again (for some reason). This is a bug in El Cap.

Comment: Is the top entry in your Favorites “iCloud Drive?” If so, you might try moving another folder to the top position and re-booting. A non-default folder, for instance.

I suspect that it’s something to do with iCloud Drive with respect to Favorites. I noticed that on one of my El Cap MacBooks, the fix stayed, but on another MacBook, it didn’t. The only difference was that iCloud Drive was the top entry in the one that kept disappearing. Now both are ok.

Comment: My top item is 'Devices' - iCloud Drive isn't listed so your hypothesis appears wrong and I predict both your machines will fail again.

Comment: This worked for me, at least for now - will see if the problem crops up again!

Comment: Thanks! This is the best fix, the other one involving deleting the files will make you reconfigure Finder again.

Comment: This worked for me, and was a better fix than deleting prefs since I don't have to waste time trying to remember my settings.  I wonder if it has anything to do with Parallels, which is filling my sidebar with copies of the same WIndoze drive...

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Rebooted, this worked for me. Will see if it holds.

Comment: All you have to do is relaunch the Finder. You don't need to drag anything to the sidebar first, and you don't need to reboot.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem.  I resolved it by going into the Finder and making a change to the Favorites area (eg dragged a folder in Favorites up one position).  After closing the finder window and reopening to make sure the change stuck, I rebooted.  File/Open then worked as normal.

Comment: This is a really frustrating issue.  It's amazing how something so simple that causes so many headaches when it is not working properly.

Comment: that was great... I didn't even have to reboot, just restart Finder after moving one sidebar item one position up

Comment: this killed my favorites from finder too, lol )) ok, fallback to cleaning preferences

Comment: This one works for me, and even better is a) non-technical and b) doesn't nuke your favourites. I presume it works for everyone!?

Answer (score 17):

The solutions above are both complicated and do not work. Kill `sharedfilelistd` and restart Finder. Problem solved (at least for a week or two according to my experience).

1. Launch the Activity Monitor,
2. Kill as many processes called `sharedfilelistd` as you can,
3. Hold Option/Alt key and right click Finder icon in the dock,
4. Relaunch Finder,
5. Enjoy.

Comment: wow! The first thing that really works, besides restarting...

Comment: Great to hear, please upvote my comment to the original question so more people will see this solution (you might need to click Show more comments to see it). Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me when other solutions (including the bash one-liner by Christophe Marois) did not! I'm running El Capitan 10.11.6 for reference.

Comment: This should be the only answer.

Comment: Fixed the problem I had on Sierra

Answer (score 16):

Go to **Finder -> Preferences -> Sidebar**, and put a check next to all your *Favorites*.

[image: Finder - Preferences...]
[image: Finder Preferences - Sidebar]

Installing El Capitan might have reset a few of your original settings (it reset my desktop backgrounds). It comes with the territory when installing major updates, but this should fix it.

Comment: Negative. Doesn't fix it :(

Comment: This worked for me in finder, but not in file open panels.

Comment: The problem doesn't lie with Finder, but in the file open/close dialogs.

Comment: Right, this wasn't about a Finder issue, but with a problem occurring *only* on open/save dialogs.  Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Fixed it for me just fine, the accepted answer removed everything for me ... so IMO this is the best answer

Answer (score 6):

Open a Finder window; you can drag folders onto the sidebar, and they’ll appear under a badly-named “Favorites” section.

Weird, but I think I like it. Keeps the plebeians out of trouble, makes it mo’ fancier for power users.

**EDIT**  haha it doesn’t have any memory… stuff dropped into Favorites disappears. What is going on here… filed in Apple Radar #22916266

Comment: What is "Apple Radar"?

Comment: Apple’s bug tracker

https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks, I thought so. I can't seem to find the bug with that ID. Can you tell my what the status is?

Answer (score 3):

Today I received a reply to this very bug report I posted in nov, 2016. It's resolved in 10.13 GM, according to it.

[image: Issue is resolved according to apple]

Comment: Holy s$^t. Like more than a year after it was first reported, and many iterations of OS X later... Apple thinks the new major update might fix it. Let's see.

Comment: My mistake... may that "nearly TWO years after it was reported here..."