# "File Open" dialogue missing "All my files"

Tags: finder, macos

In my finder sidebar, the first item is "All my files", followed by "iCloud Drive" and all my custom folders.

**In "File Open" dialogue boxes, all the items are showing *except* "All my files".** This has been missing since I upgraded to 'El Capitan'.

This previous question answers what happens to the entire list of Favourites, but doesn't answer what has happened to the "All my files" item:
["File Open" dialog is missing sidebar items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208205/file-open-dialog-is-missing-sidebar-items)

**Is there a way of getting "All my files" back into the File Open list?** It's the most useful option if you are trying to open the last modified file on your system. If you save a JPG from one file and want to load it in another program, the easier way to do is to his "File Open", "All my files" and it's there sorted by date at the top of the list.

Any ideas?