# Finder Window when Uploading or Opening Files Missing Items

Tags: finder, macos

For some reason, my file window when I am opening a file/folder or uploading something the sidebar is missing a lot of items which makes navigating to my destination a pain. What am I missing? My normal finder window is fine and isn't missing any items. I tried to go into the library>preferences>and deleting any com.apple.finder.plist like in another thread but I didn't find any files like that in my library. I searched my entire mac for them and didn't find any.

I'm using El Capitan.

[image]

Comment: When looking for your Library folder, please make sure to look in the Library folder for your User (/Users/USER/Library), not the root Library folder (/Library). The first answer in that question indicates how to do that.

Comment: I swear I'm following the steps and am still not finding any com.apple.finder.plist.

Comment: when in your /Users/USER/Library/Preferences folder, have you tried: sorting by name? typing the name of the file directly into the Finder window? or using the Search field? As an additional thing, have you tried a simple (without deleting anything) restart of your Mac?

Comment: I figured out why I was having issues- for whatever reason my USER window wasn't showing the library folder to me. So I had to "show view options" to see it. No wonder I was having confusions on your answer. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When finder is the current app, hit  <kbd>command</kbd>  and  <kbd>,</kbd>  at the same time. Click the `Sidebar` tab. You can then select the things you want to show up in window. If they are already selected, try un-selecting them and re-selecting them.

Edit: As @NetherLinks mentioned, a few good answers are over at ["File Open" dialog is missing sidebar items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208205/file-open-dialog-is-missing-sidebar-items). Try them if mine doesn't work.