# Empty favorites sidebar of third-party applications

Tags: finder, macos, sidebar, third-party

From my update to **El Capitan** (now at 10.11.3), I've some difficulties with sidebars.

My **Finder**'s sidebar working very well and can be very complete :

[image]

But third-party applications (like Preview, Acrobat Reader, Sublime Text…) don't recovers Finder's sidebar in the window when, usually, you are opening a file :

[image]

I tried to add by drag'n'drop my favorites folders to the sidebar but each application has its own and if I quit and restart the application, I'm losing all my favorites, going back to the minimal sidebar (like second picture).

It seems this window is not an instance of Finder window, because as you can see in my 2 screenshots: Finder can shows my hidden files but not third-party applications.

Does anyone has a similar problem? Any idea to save definitively a sidebar for all applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this similar thread with different terms :

["File Open" dialog is missing sidebar items](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208205/file-open-dialog-is-missing-sidebar-items)

For me, delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` and reboot worked well.