# Favorite list of servers of "Connect to Server" window disappears

Tags: finder, macos

Usually, when I connect to a server (cmd "⌘" + K), I can see the list of my favorite servers :

[image: Connect to Server with favorites]

But after upgrading to El Capitan (Mac OS 10.11.X) and after freshly booting my MacBook, this list sometimes disappears and I can't add a new server to it ("+" button doesn't works) :

[image: Connect to Server without favorites]

Does anyone have a similar problem and knows how to resolve it?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  I just (within the past 48 hours) upgraded a 2009 MBP and 2012 iMac to 10.11 and both are working fine here.    Is this a clean install, an in-place upgrade or a migration from an older version of OS X?

Comment: I'm upgrading my 2011 MacBook Pro (was on Snow Leopard) to newer's Mac OS version each time from the beginning and I have never encountered serious problems. May be it's problem of Finder's cache linked to my other unsolved problem : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227112/empty-favorites-sidebar-of-third-party-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too. Here's how I fixed it: delete the folder ~Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/ and then use Activity Monitor to kill the sharedfilelistd process belonging to your user. Then I relaunched Finder for good measure. Works now!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my iMac running 10.11.6. I opened Activity Monitor and killed all **sharedfilelistd** processes. (There were two. One under my account and one under root)  I then killed the Finder, also using Activity Monitor, and relaunched it by clicking on it in the Dock.

All of my saved favorites then appeared when I opened the Connect to Server dialog.